# How to reorder (or create a new) a Javascript array with PHP by using Database column values as a reference

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm building a leaderboard table using HTML, Php and Javascript, but I've gotten stuck trying to iterate through an array while creating a second array in Php.

I have a table in my database named "scores" which contains two columns: "id" and "score".
The rows in this table aren't ordered in any way.

I'm trying to send a Javascript array of IDs to my database using Ajax. When it gets there I want to create and return a new array which will contain the exact same ID numbers, except they will be ordered by the value of the scores that are associated with them in the database.

For example, this could be my table:

```
id   ¦ score
--------------
0002 ¦  400 ¦       
0007 ¦  100 ¦
0003 ¦  250 ¦
0012 ¦  800 ¦
0004 ¦  900 ¦
0102 ¦  700 ¦
0025 ¦  600 ¦
```

The Ajax to send the array:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'scripts/reorderarray.php',
data: {'oldArray' : oldArray},
type: "POST",
success: function(response){
// use the response (the response will be the new, reordered array)
}
});
```

This could be the array of IDs I'm sending to the database:
`oldArray = [0003, 0102, 0002, 0025];`

What I want to do is reorder this array, so that it's ordered from highest score to lowest. Going by the above table, this would mean the new array should be in this order:

`newArray = [0102, 0025, 0002, 0003];`

I've looked into using a foreach loop but then realised that this method only looks at each array object individually, whereas I need to look at all objects at the same time in order to reorder them.

I was thinking the logic might be something along the lines of the following:

`SELECT id FROM scores WHERE scores.id = (the ID's I've sent in my array), ORDER BY score DESC`

Would I need to include both the IDs and scores in my query result, order by score Descending, insert both into an associative array, and then somehow extract the IDs from the associative array. Would this be the only way to get the IDs into the correct order?

Or is it possible to insert individual IDs into the new array and order them correctly at the same time, if so, how do you go about this?

I'm totally lost on how to achieve this, thank you in advance for any help, advice or examples.

**UPDATE**

Current PHP attempt:

```
<?php

$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


//    $IDs    = json_decode($_GET['oldArray']);
//Trying this method of setting the posted array as $IDs:
      $IDs    = $_POST['oldArray'];


$array  = array(); // Array which will be used to do some stuff
$ret    = array(); // Array to return
$scores = array(); // List of the scores


    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `score` 
    FROM scores WHERE `id` = :oldArray");

//        $stmt->bindParam(':oldArray', $oldArray);

          $stmt->bindParam(':oldArray', $IDs);  


    foreach($IDs as $ID) {

//Unsure of the correct syntax here:
  $score = rand(1, 1000); // get the score stored into your database using $ID
  $oldArray = $ID
  $stmt->execute();

  $array[$score] = $ID;
  $scores[]      = $score; // Add the score to the list
}

rsort($scores); // Try array by DESC score


foreach($scores as $score) { // For each score
  $ret[] = $array[$score];
}

die(json_encode($ret)); // Output as JSON


}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**2nd UPDATE**

This is what is currently returned from the php file (the IDs are in the same order as they were sent (the wrong order) and an error code):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "1015797342265293"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "622453852408024"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "10206545343743554"
}
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in <b>/home/Games/Puzzle/scripts/reorderarray.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
```

Comment: There is an error in your post I think : You say that the array must be ordered from highest to lowest, but `0002` is before `0003` but after `0025`... Is the valid array : `newArray = [0102, 0025, 0003, 0002]` ?

Comment: Hi @ClementNerma thanks for your question, no it's not an error, by ordered from highest to lowest I'm talking about the scores that are associated with those IDs in the database, so the scores for the IDs ``[0102, 0025, 0002, 0003]`` are "700", "600", "400" and "250" respectively, so they're now in the correct order. I'm trying to reorder them by using their scores as the reference.

Comment: You'll have to pass a JSON object to the PHP page with ID and scores, or two arrays, the first with IDs and the second with scores. I'll try to make a tiny script...

Comment: Hi again @ClementNerma that would be awesome thanks!

Comment: I'm making the script but why do you want to order the array in PHP instead of JavaScript ?

Comment: Hi again, I want to do that because the scores only exist in my database. I'm sending an array of IDs to my database (I'm not sending an associative array, I'm only sending IDs, not scores), when it reaches the database, I want to check the corresponding score for each ID, and then rearrange those IDs into an order that runs from highest score to lowest score, but I don't want the score to be included inside the new array, I don't want the array that is returned to be an associative one, unless there is some way to extract the IDs in the correct order from the associative array later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script :

**script.js**

```
var oldArray = ['0002', '0007', ...]; // ID must be between quotes like here

// Ajax request
$.ajax({
  url: 'scripts/reorderarray.php',
  data: {'oldArray' : oldArray},
  type: "POST",
  success: function(response) {
    // use the response (the response will be the new, reordered array)
    try { newArray = JSON.parse(response); }
    catch(e) { alert('Invalid response from server'); }
    // expected result :
    // newArray = {"0004":900,"0012":800,"0102":700,"0025":600,"0002":400,"0003":250,"0007":100}
  }
});
```

**script.php**

```
    <?php

$IDs    = json_decode($_GET['oldArray']);
$array  = array(); // Array which will me used to do some stuff
$ret    = array(); // Array to return
$scores = array(); // List of the scores

foreach($IDs as $ID) {
  $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT score FROM scores WHERE id = :id');
  $req->bindValue(':id', $ID);
  $score = $pdo->execute()->fetch()['score']; // get the score stored into your database using $ID
  $array[$score] = $ID;
  $scores[]      = $score; // Add the score to the list
}

rsort($scores); // Try array by DESC score

foreach($scores as $score) { // For each score
  $ret[] = $array[$score];
}

die(json_encode($ret)); // Output as JSON
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this code a try, unfortunately I'm not sending an associative array to the database/php file. I'm sending only an array of IDs. And I'm hoping to have an array of only IDs returned back, ie, I don't want an associative array, but if an associative array is the only type that can be returned, then is there some way to create a new array from that which contains only the IDs in the correct order, and not the scores? This would be like splitting the array into two columns, or pushing every second array item into a new array. Is such a thing possible? Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my post, now the array sent to the PHP page is a list of IDs, and the returned array is a list of IDs too, ordered by score DESC.

Comment: Hi @clementnerma that's awesome thanks! I'm working with your code, but I'm using PDO to connect to the database and a prepared statement. Where you have the score randomized I'm unsure of the correct syntax to get each IDs relevant score to compare/reorder them. I've added my current attempt with your code to the end of my question, could you take a look and let me know what you think? Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my post. Where you have the `$score = $pdo->....` replace put the request and exec.

Comment: I've edited again so you can see a sample of prepared PDO request which will get the score

Comment: Hi, thanks again. I'm trying your updated code, but I'm getting an error with the ``foreach``, this is the error: 
``<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/Games/Puzzle/scripts/reorderarray.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
[]``  But line 20 is this: ``foreach($IDs as $ID){`` I don't understand what's wrong with that line, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Put a `var_dump($IDs);` before the `foreach` and post the result here please.

Comment: It says ``NULL`` that's strange because right before the ajax in the Javascript file I put ``console.log(oldArray);`` and the array is showing up correctly in the console. Could there be an issue with the ``$IDs = json_decode($_GET['oldArray']);``

Comment: I tried changing the json_decode line and I've added a second update to the question with the result, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116312/discussion-between-clementnerma-and-emily).